# Unable to edit java source code(the old fashion way) in NetBeans when I am using Windows Builder Swing designer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to have the option from going to the palette and adding my widgets to actually going to the source code and writing out new code. In eclipse mars ide, it allows me to change the source code and change the design ui by adding new widgets. NetBeans won't allow me to write out the code, specifically the code in highlighted in the grey area:[image]

What do I need to change in netbeans for it to allow me to write out the code highlighted in the grey area

Comment: That's the problem with GUI builders. You get to create things easily, but then you're no longer in control.

Comment: That is not the case when I use the eclipse mars ide

Comment: It just means that Eclipse's GUI builder doesn't protect its code as jealously. Netbeans makes sure that you can't break the code, so you can keep using the GUI builder to modify things. If you write custom code with Eclipse, you can break the code so that the GUI builder won't work with it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist (and willing to "detach" it from gui designer), open the file with notepad or other text-editor, remove all the comments before the method name.

Comment: So I cannot edit the source code manually in net beans while using a gui builder?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks @Lee, this saved my life.. It's really hard to find the reason for this, especially if you never used Java and NetBean.. Could you please elaborate your answer or perhaps leaving us some reference so other user can understood better?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the code of a specific composant:
Right click on the componant of the ui. --> customize code.--> change default code to custom code.